# Getting highest number from a json file python

Tags: json, python-3.8

I've got a json file like

```
{
    "bob": "5",
    "tim": "8",
    "alex": "10"
}
```

How could I get the highest number from this list? In this example it could return `"alex": "10"`

Answer (score 0):

I'd parse the JSON using `loads`, and extract the maximum based on the maximum value, converted to an int:

```py
import json
jsonStr = '{"bob": "5", "tim": "8", "alex": "10"}' # Or load it from a file, etc...
d = json.loads(jsonStr)
maxTuple = max(d.items(), key = lambda i : int(i[1]))
```